# Failed to connect to repository Error while Building the Maven Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, devops, integration, credentials

Here is the error I get when trying to configure the SCM URL of the job:

```
Failed to connect to repository : 
  Command 
  "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -- https://xgitlab.asee.org/asee-fro/asee-fro.git HEAD" 
  returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://xgitlab.asee.org/asee-fro/asee-fro.git/'
```

How can I get past this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [Jenkins Credentials plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials/) installed, you should:

- register the right account/password required to access `xgitlab.asee.org/asee-fro/asee-fro`

[image: credentials]

- use that credential in the configuration of your job

[image: creds job]

Source: [Jenkins and GIT Integration using SSH Key](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jenkins-and-git-integration-using-ssh-key/) (using an SSH creds, but the same process applies for an HTTPS creds)

Comment: Hello VonC thank you for your response I will check and get back to you.